# How to disable all Drupal 7 error and exception handlers

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I want to create a simple PHP status file at the root of a Drupal website. This file will be called by a monitoring system such as Nagios. I want to fully customize the output and add some additional details into the error message (as a plain text string).

I've tried the following code:

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', __DIR__);
require_once realpath(DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc');
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

restore_exception_handler();
restore_error_handler();

function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}
set_exception_handler('exception_handler');

function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
  echo "PHP Error: [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
  return true;
}
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");

try {
  db_query('SELECT COUNT(nid) FROM {node}');
  echo 'ok';
}
catch (\PDOException $e) {
  echo "Database problem";
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Unexecpted error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

However, when I try to disable the database (by stopping the service), a Drupal custom error appears in HTML format.

Answer (score 0):

You must go to `admin/config/development/logging` and check the option `None` to hide errors